# Access message inbox without Content UrI (content//:sms)

Tags: android

I want to access the messages stored in inbox through my android
project. I have tried the method of forming URI for sms (content://sms/
inbox) and then quering it for various parametres.

But I cannot find any documentation for reading inbox sms in the
standard Android Developr Docs.
It was mentioned at various websites that this content has been
removed from the standard sdk. The application may not support higher
version of android.

So, how can I create an apllication to read sms from inbox that is
reliable in furture version of android.

Please help !!

Comment: Good article here: http://mobdev.olin.edu/mobdevwiki/FrontPage/Tutorials/SMS%20Messaging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it works well in my milestone (sdk update 2.1)

```
 public List<String> getSms() {
        Uri mSmsQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        List<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = mContentResolver.query(mSmsQueryUri, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor == null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "cursor is null. uri: " + mSmsQueryUri);
                return messages;
            }

            for (boolean hasData = cursor.moveToFirst(); hasData; hasData = cursor.moveToNext()) {
                final String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
                messages.add(body);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return messages;
    }
```

Please make sure you have the read sms permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply. Although this way of accessing the inbox works, but it has been removed from the standard sdk (as mentioned at various websites post including android developer) . There is no documentation at the android developer docs regarding the content provider  content://sms. This method may not be working in next highre versions of android.  That is why I am looking for any reliable way of accesing the inbox (not by content uri as mentioned in the subject of post ).

Please let me know if any one know other way of doing so.
Thanks

Comment: Did you get a solution to access inbox?

Comment: @qrtt1: Yes. It's useful for me. Thanks a lot. By the way is there any method for getting installed applications like this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard SmsMessage use to **send** messages. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html

However, I think the Content Provider solution is more stable than Concrete Class, because Content Provider is the abstract layer to access data in cross-application case. In long-time view, everything could be changed. To face it, developers will benefit from adopting design pattern, a wrapper class to manipulate the content provider (Facade), or use Data Access Object pattern, etc.

In android configuration file, we can limit sdk level to prevent from something lost:

```
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="5" 
    android:maxSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="7" />
```

I'm a newbie in android development, even if I have read many documents or books, I know there are a lot of black magic in the source code.  The change is too fast to write the complete document (keeps it up to date is impossible), so don't  worry about the AUTHORITY or Class changed.

my 2 cents